# Run a Windows service once

Tags: windows-10, windows-services

I have an .exe file which is a Windows service. I want to run that file, but only once. I don't want to install it, or anything like that.

Is there a way to do that in Windows 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think so unless you can get the source code.

The Windows service exe has different structure than a normal exe and contains only methods like `OnStart`, `OnStop`, so there is not any defined point to start execution of code within that executable file.

You would have to use some tool that emulates [svchost.exe](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-svchost-exe#1TC=windows-7), but I doubt there exists anything like that.

You can install it, start it, stop it and uninstall it by a batch command, but that requires local admin privileges.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I had that figured out yes, and was hoping there would be some kind of debugging tool available for services.

Comment: When I debug services, I create a separate debugging method and compile it conditionally into a debug build, so debugging services works differently.